# How to increase the size of the workbench in gnuradio-companion 3.7?

Tags: gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

I am working with `gnuradio-companion` in (End-of-Life) GNU Radio 3.7, working on a bigger project with a lot of blocks for the first time. The space on the workbench is getting scarce.

Do you know if it is possible to increase the size of the workbench?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Starting with GNU Radio 3.8, this is no longer necessary: the canvas auto-adjusts its size, and you can zoom around in it (usually, using ctrl+scroll wheel).

So, if this is a problem you're encountering, you're using the [End-Of-Life](https://www.gnuradio.org/news/2021-11-18-gnuradio-v3.7-end-of-maint/) GNU Radio 3.7 release series (or older). **You should not be doing that. It's time to upgrade your GNU Radio.**

To preserve the old answer:

Double-Click on the "*Options*" block and adjust the "Canvas Size" (it's `width, height` in pixels).

Another good approach to keep your flow graph manageable is to take groups of blocks and put them into "hier" blocks (select connected blocks, right click, more, Create hier); use "Pad Sinks" and "Pad Sources" to create in- and outputs for your new hier block, and use that hier block in place of the bunch of blocks, to keep your flow graph tidy!

Comment: I tried but I don't have enough reputation yet. I will do it as soon as I have 15 points :-)

Comment: ha, sorry, forgot that :) Have a great day!

Comment: Have my upvote! You have freed my design from its cell